# send the chosen dropdown item to the view when onselect

Tags: django, drop-down-menu, django-templates

I want to send the value of the chosen dropdown item to my view when `onselect` or `onchange` option, not when a button clicked to submit.

My goal is to filter a list of model objects immediately by the chosen data.

I don't find any clear answer and I'm confused about that.

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

you should solve your problem using AJAX

1. user selects item `X` from dropdown
2. you send a background request with `data=X`
3. there is a new endpoint in your site (maybe API?) which processes `X` and returns a response (response can be json or something like that)
4. user gets response from step2, now update your from response data (if needed)

check [this](https://realpython.com/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/) link to get a general idea of how to use ajax with djnago